Remove parts of filenames that are not floating numbers
I have a directory which contains filenames including IDs in front, e.g:
32.04 Wybrane wzory matematyczne
32.01 Funkcje
31.01 Opracowania lektur EM 2023

The desired filenames after the change would respectively be:
32.04
32.01
31.01

I have other number formats in the directory, such as 30-39, or 31 {filename} so I want to specifically target the files with this floating notation.
The script should run from parent through all its subdirectories.

You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

autoload zmv
zmv -i '(**/)(<->.<->) *' '$1$2'


-i - interactive mode; can be removed if you are comfortable with the result.
The -n (no-op / dry run) option is also available for testing patterns without actually renaming any files.
(**/)(<->.<->) * - 'from' pattern.

(**/) - recursive glob. Note that in zsh 5.9, the parens are required, even if the component is not referenced in the 'to' pattern.
<->.<-> - since <-> is a glob pattern for any number, this will find number.number.
 * - the rest of the filename.


$1$2 - 'to' pattern. $n is the nth parenthesized expression in the 'from' pattern.

$1 - from (**/), i.e. the directory part of the full filename, with the trailing /. This will be an empty string for files in the current directory.
$2 - from (<->.<->), the floating-point-like number at the start of the filename.



More about zmv.
More zmv examples.
A longer zmv explanation. The description there covers many of the operators used in a previous version of this answer (zmv '(*/)#<->.<-> *' '${f:h}/${${f:t}%% *}').

You could also use flag -n to do a dry-run. This way you can quickly see the result before attempting to execute the command.

@MasoudGhaderi - that's a good note; I'll add it to the answer. I've been using -i instead of -n in zmv solutions after a commenter mentioned that the -n had proven  confusing. Turns out that the output from zmv -n and zmv look very similar - it is not obvious that it is a no-op. zmv -i will actually rename the files, while still acting as a check on incorrect patterns.
